# LINQ compound aggregation

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple LINQ question:

I have a collection of FooBars. A Foobar has a foo property and a bar property.
I want to aggregate both foo and bar without running through my collection of foobars more than once.

Ie. I want something equivalent to SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(Foo), SUM(Bar) From FooBars
```

or

```
int fooSum, barSum;
foreach (var foobar in foobars)
{
   fooSum += foobar.Foo;
   barSum += foobar.Bar;
}
```

Is there an elegant way to write this with a compound select (or similar) in LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx), holding the running totals in an anonymous type or tuple. Though I would probably just go with a plain `foreach` loop myself.

```
var result = foobars.Aggregate(new { FooSum = 0, BarSum = 0 },
                               (a, x) => new {
                                                 FooSum = a.FooSum + x.Foo,
                                                 BarSum = a.BarSum + x.Bar
                                             });

Console.WriteLine("FooSum=" + result.FooSum + ", BarSum=" + result.BarSum);
```

Comment: @LukeH: won't it create a big object overhead when `foobars` contains a lot of elements, because you are creating a new instance of the anonymous type for each iteration?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, indeed, and the same would apply if you used something like `Tuple<int,int>` too since they're also ref types. I suppose you could create a custom struct to do the job, or (mis)use a built-in struct such as `KeyValuePair<int,int>`. I suppose you could also use something like `int[2]` as the accumulator and just mutate it on each iteration. With these suggestions it's getting *really* ugly, a `foreach` loop is definitely the better option.

Comment: @LukeH: Have a look at my solution. Does it have the same problem? IMHO not, because I am reusing that anonymous type. About ugly: It already is... :-D

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think your version will compile. Anon types are immutable.

Comment: @LukeH: Oh my... Right you are.